# Is it possible to relauches an ipad application?

Tags: objective-c, performance, ipad, memory, webview

I have an application used mainly with uiwebview since we have a lot of work based on the website so it is quicker to show it directly on webview without re-coding it. The problem with webview, it is very expensive on memory. The UI is running fine throughout 10 times of going through from beginning of the application to the end of the application and repeating the process. On the other hand, the webview started to get slow when it doing some javascript animation using Canvas object. I have put in some code to remove NSUrlCache when it received warning.

Our application is based on navigating through stacked pages. When it gets to the end, user basically goes back to beginning. In my mind, I wanted to relaunch the application when I knows the application started to run slow. I know it is not a good idea to do this but I don't know what is the best way of reclaim the memory. I have looked through all of my code and have released what i have to released. The Application is going well without problem but it is just the uiwebview caused the performance.

Please Help...

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Not possible. You'll have to find a different way to address your performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

If UIWebView is bottlenecking your application then the solution would be to NOT use UIWebView. You cannot simply "restart" or "reset" your application. If performance is decreasing over time as your app is being used then this suggests that you might not be managing your memory or object allocations properly. You can use the Leaks instrument to debug your application and try to hunt down memory leaks and you can use the Allocations instrument to analyze your object allocations.